# No css and images getting applied in cakephp 1.3 for iis

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to use IIS for CakePHP 1.3 but no CSS and images are getting applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all `.htaccess` file in place.

Cakephp request is trying to get the css file from `css` folder but it is enable to have the proper path, `.htaccess` files in place to route it to the `webroot` and not to a `controller`!

Also check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

[**SEE HERE**](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/filippo.toso/2008/01/29/cakephp-on-iis).